# Laravel is telling me undefined index but dd says it's there

Tags: php, laravel-5, illuminate-container

Started a new Laravel 5.2 project and implemented the default authentication that comes with it.  I wanted to modify it so that the registration form has a field for first name and last name instead of just 'name'.  I added the fields in the view, the verification, and the model.  When I test I get the following:[image]

Line 71 is in the following code block for last name or 'lname'.

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname '],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

When I add a `dd` on the data array right before the `return/create` like this:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        dd($data);
        return User::create([
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname '],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

I get this:
[image]

We can clearly see that `lname` is, in fact, present in that array and should not be an undefined index.  What's going on?

Answer (score 5):

change this

```
'lname' => $data['lname '],
```

to this

```
'lname' => $data['lname'], # additional space within the key
```

In the error check line two, you can see `'lname '`

Comment: @lola_the_coding_girl ha ha. I had this issue already + many times ;)

Comment: Not my DV, but maybe because it should be closed as a typo instead?

Comment: @aynber  thanks. `'lname '` is an error. That's what pointed here

Comment: I attempted to delete this question because it's a stupid typo but SO wouldn't let me because someone had answered it.  So I guess the help to future readers will be "check for typos first".